# Ubuntu install hangs after creating partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, partitioning

I've been trying to install Ubuntu for quite some time now with no success. I was trying for a while with an older version, but now I'm trying with 14.04. I've tried to boot from a CD, but that usually hangs/fails. Sometimes, it just gives me an error: check cable connection - Pxe-mof: exiting intel pxe rom. Since then, I've tried doing a boot from USB. I'm using UNetbootin and it started a few times but ended up freezing when I tried to input anything with my keyboard.

Now, the installer doesn't recognize any partitions so I've been setting up my own through the installer interface. I create a swap partition: /swap 19998MB and a root fs partition: / xxxxxxMB with EXT4 utilizing the rest of my free space. I don't intend to dual boot. After I start the process after this, it just goes to a screen with the loading/spinning cursor, but doesn't do anything. My computer's fans and HDD also stop.

Any suggestions/input?

Also, I'm trying to put it on a Dell xps 15z (only about a year old). And I don't seem to be able to change any of the boot parameters while using UNetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

Try redownloading the image with a torrent (so it auto-verifies the file for you) and remaking the USB stick. The ISO to USB process is notoriously finicky, and you may be using a bad image.